# VB: Sleep API Issue

Tags: vba, timer, powerpoint

I'm creating a countdown timer in powerpoint and utilizing the kernel32 sleep API (in ppt).
When exiting slideshow mode (but keeping the the macro running) after the timer has been running for a substantial amount of time causes my windows desktop to completely haywire and become completely unusable (screen goes a weird grey colour). The desktop occaisionally comes back and starts working again, however opening IE causes the screen to get all screwey again.

Any idea what might be causing this problem? Timer code below

```
            Do While (TMinus > -1)
            'Suspend program execution for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
            Sleep 1000

            'set hours, muinutes and seconds left based on number of seconds left (TMinus)
            cHour = Int(TMinus / 3600)
            cMin = Int((TMinus Mod 3600) / 60)
            cSec = Int((TMinus Mod 3600) Mod 60)

            'Change text in Shape 1 (timer) to reflect changed time

            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(TimeSerial(cHour, cMin, cSec), "hh:mm:ss")

            'decrement the countdown
            TMinus = TMinus - 1
            'Refreshes the display
            DoEvents
        Loop
```

Comment: `DoEvents` shouldn't be necessary when using `Sleep`, since `Sleep` yields control to other processes while your macro sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

Using DoEvents can cause some rather strange problems.  Try using a timer instead of Sleep/DoEvents.